# If you had an algorithm of O(n^3), how many elements can you do at the same time then with a computer that is 10x as fast?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, execution-time

Could it be as simple as multiplying the amount of elements processed by the slower computer by a factor of 10? So for example if the "slow" computer processed 3 elements, the faster computer handles 30 elements in the same time frame.

Comment: define 10x as fast

Comment: Big O notation ignores the constant multiplier, therefore `O(n)` is the same as `O(n * 10)`... fo this reason, using a computer 10 times faster, is useless, becuase you would have `O(n^3 / 10)` that is still `O(n^3)`.... in the best case where you can make use completely of the new computing power, that is not an obvious thing

Comment: You can process 2.15443469003 times bigger n in the same time (10^(1/3)). So if the slower machine needs 1 hour for n = 100, you can process n = 215 in an hour with the faster machine (and not 10*100 = 1000).

Comment: @TheFool This question was meant to understand how system depend effects would influence the execution speed of an algorithm, 10x was just used as an arbitrary value.

Comment: These questions show a wrong understanding of time complexity. Time complexity says something about *asymptotic* behaviour, not about the time needed for actual finite input sizes. Even if an algorithm is O(n³), and you know the time it takes to process 50 elements, you know *nothing* (!) about the time that it will take for processing 100 elements, let be how many you can do on a faster PC. You can only guess, and be completely wrong. This is because O(n³) does not reveal anything about the influence of a n² overhead, a linear overhead or even a constant overhead.

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Isn't Big-O system independent?

Comment: @GhettoThief, no it isn't dependent on system.

Comment: I understand that 10 was arbitrary. But I am asking, what does it even mean faster? Can it do x more operations in the same time?

Comment: @trincot This question is a derivation of a question I found in one of the practice exams. I do understand that Big Oh is used to develop the upper bounds. The thing is I don't know how to answer the question because of how to factor in the system dependent effects into the equation.

Comment: @TheFool In this case I suspect the faster computer can perform 10 operations in the time the slow computer does 1 operation

Comment: @GhettoThief, the question cannot be answered, and if I were to do an exam where this question came up, I would write my reasoning as to why this cannot be generally known. Often teachers are even wrongly assuming you can do such calculations with time complexity. You cannot.

Comment: @trincot Alright, thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: Usually such questions are just for showing that a faster computer doesn't help much if the complexity is bad. So the message is better invest in a good algorithm than a fast computer. Or in other words: time complexity matters.

Comment: You would only be able to answer this question if the time period were infinite.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited]
The question seemed obvious, but looking at the comments to the question post maybe it is worth answering it:

O(n^3) means that when n grows, the time to execute it T(n) grows as T(n)<K·n^3 when n grows. This only gives you a bound on T(n). For example as mentionned in the comments n.log(n) is O(n.log(n)), as well as O(n^3), but also O(n^123).

If T(n)=n^(1/k) with k very high then you can process 10^k more data. If k growths to the infinite, you can process an infinite number of elements. T(n) being "at most" k.n^3 for large n, the correct answer is :
"Between 10^(1/3) times and infinitely as many elements for large n"

Comment: Note than big-O is used to denote *upper bounds*: O(n log n) is part of O(n^3) as is O(1), *will be close and closer* does not necessarily hold.

Comment: Why exactly do you say "infinitely as many"?

Comment: I mean, if T(n) is constant, then sure, the faster computer can do "infinitely many" in the time. But so did the slower computer.

Comment: If T(n)=n^(1/100) then a 10 times faster computer can process 10^100 more data. Take this to the limit for n^(1/k)